# Visual Studio Code complains that it "Cannot find namespace" for types defined in *.d.ts files

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, yeoman, visual-studio-code

I created a new project using the [gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) Yeoman generator with language set to TypeScript. Then ran the [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) build process and also opened the page in a web browser, which all worked without any bigger problems. I only had to replace `ref: "master"` in the `tsd.json` with `ref: "1.4.1"` to make the build work. Basically I executed following commands:

```
yo gulp-angular
vim tsd.json
gulp
gulp serve
code .
```

Afterwards I opened the project in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Now, Visual Studio Code complains for example that it *"Cannot find namespace 'ng'"* for each occurrence where [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) data types are used. It also complains about [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) and other typings defined in `*.d.ts` files.

The project's `tsd.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "1.4.1",
  "path": ".tmp/typings",
  "bundle": ".tmp/typings/tsd.d.ts"
}
```

The `.tmp/typings` folder contains following files:

```
angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.d.ts
angularjs/angular-animate.d.ts
angularjs/angular-cookies.d.ts
angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts
angularjs/angular-resource.d.ts
angularjs/angular-sanitize.d.ts
angularjs/angular.d.ts
jquery/jquery.d.ts
moment/moment-node.d.ts
moment/moment.d.ts
toastr/toastr.d.ts
tsd.d.ts
```

To give an example of one of the source files where Visual Studio Code is complaining, here is the `navbar.directive.ts` file:

```
module editorTs {
  'use strict';

  /** @ngInject */
  export function acmeNavbar(): ng.IDirective {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        creationDate: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'app/components/navbar/navbar.html',
      controller: NavbarController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };

  }

  /** @ngInject */
  class NavbarController {
    public relativeDate: string;

    constructor(moment: moment.MomentStatic) {
      this.relativeDate = moment(1444135396045).fromNow();
    }
  }
}
```

In this file Visual Studio Code is complaining about the `ng.IDirective` type that it *"Cannot find namespace 'ng'"* and it is complaining about the `moment.MomentStatic` type that it *"Cannot find namespace 'moment'"*.

**edit:**

Explicitely referencing the type definition files by adding the following to the top of `navbar.directive.ts` removes the problem:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../.tmp/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../../../../.tmp/typings/moment/moment.d.ts"/>
```

But these files are already referenced in `.tmp/tsd.d.ts`, which contains the following:

```
/// <reference path="angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular-animate.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular-cookies.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular-resource.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular-sanitize.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="moment/moment-node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="moment/moment.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="toastr/toastr.d.ts" />
```

So there should be no need to explicitly reference the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot find namespace 'ng'"

Make sure the project contains no reference to `declare module ng`. Same for moment.

## Update

based on edit in the question:

> Explicitely referencing the type definition files by adding the following to the top of navbar.directive.ts removes the problem

Please use a `tsconfig.json` : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/compilation-context.html

Comment: Running `grep -ri "declare module ng" .` only reveals one line `./bower_components/angular-ui-router/api/angular-ui-router.d.ts:declare module ng.ui {`.

Comment: Change that to `declare module angular.ui`

Comment: Tried it, but that doesn't help. I assume that somehow Visual Studio Code must be told where it can find the typings. Since `gulp build` is working the typings seem to be included correctly during build.

Comment: don't use a reference comment. Use tsconfig.json See answer update

Comment: Thanks! That helped :-). All namespaces are now detected correctly. As a side note: When I change back `declare module angular.ui` to `declare module ng.ui` in `./bower_components/angular-ui-router/api/angular-ui-router.d.ts` the `ng` namespace is still detected but not angular's definitions it contains. I have no problem with changing the file, but I wonder because both angularjs and angular ui router are widely used and I can't imagine being the first one to stumble upon that problem. But maybe they'll fix that in the future ;-). Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm. I'm having this same problem and I don't understand what the solution of "use a tsconfig.json" is. What goes in tsconfig.json?

Comment: @JasonSwett Check out this link on what put inside it: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `tsconfig.json` to the root of my VS Code project is what fixed the issue for me. Also, had to restart VS code. Here is what I put inside that file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

For more info on the `tsconfig.json` file, check out:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

Comment: This worked in Visual Studio as well. I added the default tsconfig.json supplied by Visual Studio (riglt-click project, Add New Item, search for TypeScript JSON). The exact text is slightly different from what is in this answer, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following in a discreet location in the code. Likely put there to avoid type errors. Seems like vscode encountered this and redefined the global 'angular' variable as type of 'any'.

```
var angular = window['angular'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; it appears typings was stripping the original definition file referencing the "ng" import.

Add this back to your original angular/index.d.ts file:

`// Collapse angular into ng
import ng = angular;`

Or better yet, place it in a ng.d.ts file so it's not overwritten by typings again.