# tsconfig.json: using TypeScript in a team with Atom and VSCode?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, namespaces, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

As the title of the question indicates, we are a team, which uses TypeScript, but the editors Atom *and* VSCode. We have troubles with the `tsconfig.json`.

1. VSCode does not recognize the typings, so `ng` (for *Angular 1.x*) is not known namespace for VSCode.
2. The following tsconfig.json is commented by VSCode with a

   > Matches a schema that is not allowed.

I guess, there is a connection between these issues.

---

```
{
    "compilerOptions":
        {
            "target": "es5",
            "module": "commonjs",
            "declaration": false,
            "noImplicitAny": false,
            "removeComments": true,
            "noLib": false,
            "preserveConstEnums": true,
            "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
            "outDir": "./tmp/typescript",
            "rootDir": "./our/ts/dir"
        },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
        "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
        "./bower_components/our_library/src/company/**/*.ts",
        "./typings/tsd.d.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        "./src/example.ts",
        "./src/many/many/entries/any.ts",
        "./src/lib.ts/a_library.ts",
        "./src/lib.ts/angular.ts",
        "./src/lib.ts/jquery.ts",
        "./src/lib.ts/lodash.ts",
        "./src/lib.ts/moment.ts",
        "./src/lib.ts/restangular.ts",
        "./src/lib.ts/selectize.ts",
        "./src/lib.ts/systemjs.ts",
        "./typings/tsd.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [],
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": true
    }
}
```

---

I've tried to manage the issue based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32981673/2092322), but the answer does not help (the typings are already included in the tsconfig.json). Also reading the [`tsconfig.json spec`](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig) was not very helpful, because the error message from VSCode occurrs when I remove the `filesGlob` and `atom` fields in the JSON.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For issue number 2:

You have to remove the `exclude` property. If it is used in conjunction with the `files` property the `files` property takes precedence.

You can read the full spec for valid tsconfigs here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

Comment: Perfect! This solved issue 1, either - as expected. Many, many thanks.