# TypeScript: Cannot find namespace 'ng'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use a tsconfig.json so I can avoid having  at the top of a bunch of files. But I keep getting this error:

> [ts] Cannot find namespace 'ng'. any

My `tsconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "target": "es2015",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I'm pointing it to my `index.d.ts` file, which looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="globals/angular-ui-router/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/angular/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jquery/index.d.ts" />
```

However, if I put this reference at the top of my module:

**app.controller.js**

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/index.d.ts" />

...
```

it recognises `ng` and gives me its types. Any reason why this might not be working?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32981690/1606432

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I'm using a `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? tsconfig.json functionality has been added since version 1.5.

Comment: I'm using typescript within a gulp task. Using `gulp-typescript` (2.13.5) and `tsify` (0.16.0).

Answer (score 0):

> app.controller.js

You file has a `.js` extension as is not a part of the files that match `tsconfig.json`.

## Quick Solution

Rename to `.ts` and list the file in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. My bad. The file is called `app.controller.ts`. Shouldn't I be adding my typings file paths to the `files` array in `tsconfig.json`, and not the source files (i.e. app.controller.ts)?

Comment: Just add your main file AND the typings file.